# Windows Laravel update: composer failed to open stream, permission denied

Tags: laravel, composer-php

Initially I was trying to update to Laravel 5.6 from 5.5, however nothing works anymore since I ran composer update. I can't even go back to 5.5, always get the same error:

> In Filesystem.php line 122:
>
> file_put_contents(C:\Users...\laravelprojectroot\bootstrap/cache/packages.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied

I tried deleting the cache, deleting vendor dictionary and deleting `packages.php`. Once I ran composer update, I cannot edit or delete packages.php even with root permission on my laptop.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Open cmd prompt or git bash with admin privilege, That solves this issue.

Comment: actually this worked. But I had to delete all the files in the cache folder first, which was only possible after restarting my PC. I think PHPStorm was part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create these directories if they don't exist:

- storage/framework/cache
- storage/framework/sessions
- storage/framework/views

Then delete bootstrap/cache files

Test if it works, if not, try giving the correct permissions to the storage folder: chmod -R 775 storage/